# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called when app launch from url schema

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am newbie in iOS  Development. i want to add deep linking on my app so i prefer url schema for that, so now i want to open my app from another app then app is open and instantly crashed not any one method is called.

like as here i added alert on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Finish Called" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
   [alert show];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES; 
}
```

And also this method is not call when my app is open

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    return YES;
 }
```

It just open Splash screen and crashed can any one help me for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 situations 
1. app is in suspended state
   - when u click on url then applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions will get called and u will get url in options dictionary and the openUrl method will get skipped

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   return YES; 
}
```

2. if app is in background then openUrl method only get called .

Comment: from background `openUrl` is called but if app is suspended then nothing happen.

Comment: then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions get called and u will get that url in options dictionary of this method .

Comment: Yes but i say that it not getting called `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on suspended state.and also alert will be not shown.

Comment: u will get url in key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey" check documentaion for launch option keys : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1657534-launch_options_keys

Comment: if my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is getting called then it shows alert but it not shows and it is crashed.

Comment: ok , do 1 thing show that after some delay using performSelector .

Comment: crashing ? ok is it a sample project ? then send to my mail id i will check n update u , skriyaz7@gmail.com

Comment: i send you my APPDelegate File wait. it is to big Project so.